# Why do we use the cubed difference in skewness?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Wikipedia gives the following definition for Fisher's moment coefficient of skewness:

$$
\bar{u} = E\bigg[\bigg(\frac{X - u}{\sigma}\bigg)^{3}\bigg]
$$

I understand that in calculating variance and standard deviation the reason for squaring $(X-u)$ is to make all the values positive, but I am unsure why one would cube these values for skewness. I appreciate that doing so preserves the sign of $(X - u)$ (which is relevant) but that could just as easily be achieved by not raising $(X-u)$ to any power at all, and yet that isn't how it is calculated, nor does it produce similar results.

Intuitively speaking, what's so special about $(x - u)^3$?

Comment: $E\bigg[\bigg(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\bigg)\bigg]=0$ by the definition of $\mu$. Cubing gives greater weight to extreme values

Answer (score 1):

As you said, when calculating the standard deviation, the reason for squaring is to make all the values positive, but since the skewness is a way to measure the *asymmetry* of a probability distribution function, the sign is needed.

Also, the skewness is defined in this way since it is closely related to the $4^{th}$ term of its *moment-generating function*

Comment: I see your point, but what about the observation that the sign could be preserved by not raising $(X-u)$ to any power?

Comment: @JamesHamilton If you want to measure the asymmetry of a probability distribution function, it can be done by not raising $(X-u)$ to any power at all, but the "standard" way of doing it is by raising it to the $3^{rd}$ power so, as Henry said, it gives more weight to extreme values  (if you want to give them even more weight you can raise it to the $5^{th}$ power! but that's is definitely not the "standard" way of doing it). Also, it is convenient to relate this coefficient to its moment-generating function.